# Linear mapping to fit points to subset of other points

Tags: fitting, curated-data, coordinate-transformation

I have some set of points making a specific pattern. I want to find a linear mapping (dilations + translations) to find a similar pattern in a second larger set of points. I want to find the best (or at least a good) fit in the second data. I am having a problem getting Mathematica to find the best one.

Set of points:

```
p1={{{5,80},{20,100}},{{15,90},{35,90}},{{15,75},{35,75}},{{5,55},{35,55}},{{20,25},{35,35}},{{25,30},{25,75}},{{45,85},{85,85}},{{45,85},{45,20}},{{85,85},{85,20}},{{45,25},{85,25}},{{45,55},{85,55}},{{60,85},{65,100}}};
data=Flatten[p1,1]
```

[image]

Second larger set of points:

```
cities=CityData[{Large,"China"}];
coords=Select[Map[Reverse[CityData[#,"Coordinates"]]&,cities],Length[#]==2&]
```

[image]

Here is my function to find nearest point:

```
findNearest[p_,list_]:=list[[Ordering[Map[(p[[1]]-#[[1]])^2+(p[[2]]-#[[2]])^2&,list],1]]][[1]]
```

These seems to work based on this test:

```
Graphics[{Black,Map[Point,coords],Red,Point[{112,35}],Green,Point[findNearest[{112,35},coords]]}]
```

Next I set up a measure of how close a particular mapping got the points in data to the points in coords.

```
score[a_,b_,c_,d_]:=Sum[With[{p={{a,0},{0,b}}.data[[i]]+{c,d}},Sqrt[#.#]&@(p-findNearest[p,coords])],{i,1,Length[data]}]
```

I them asked Mathematica to find the best a,b,c,d for the transformation. I added the minimum requirements on the scaling coefficients a and b so that it doesn't just shrink it to a single point.

```
sol=Minimize[{score[a,b,c,d],a>0.05,b>0.05},{a,b,c,d}][[2]]
```

This however ends up with points which looks nothing like the original shape.

```
Graphics[{Black,Map[Point,coords],Red,Map[Point,Map[{{a,0},{0,b}}.#+{c,d}/.sol&,data]],Green,Line[Map[{{a,0},{0,b}}.#+{c,d}/.sol&,p1,{2}]],Blue,Map[Point,Map[findNearest[#,coords]&,Map[{{a,0},{0,b}}.#+{c,d}/.sol&,data]]],Pink,Line[Map[findNearest[#,coords]&,Map[{{a,0},{0,b}}.#+{c,d}/.sol&,p1,{2}],{2}]]}]
```

[image: Solution found by Code]

manually trying some other mappings I find ones that look more like the original. For example with a=0.05, b=0.05, c=114, d=34.5 I get the image:

[image: Manual Solution]

Checking my 'score' for both shows that my mapping is 'worse' so my question is how do I improve my methodology so that I get a more human acceptable better mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following code finds the best fit in different scales of the pattern.
you have to choose the scale.

```
scale = .28;
mean = Table[
p1 = {{{5, 80}, {20, 100}}, {{15, 90}, {35, 90}}, {{15, 75}, {35, 
   75}}, {{5, 55}, {35, 55}}, {{20, 25}, {35, 35}}, {{25, 
   30}, {25, 75}}, {{45, 85}, {85, 85}}, {{45, 85}, {45, 
   20}}, {{85, 85}, {85, 20}}, {{45, 25}, {85, 25}}, {{45, 
   55}, {85, 55}}, {{60, 85}, {65, 100}}};
data = Flatten[p1, 1];
p1 = Partition[#*scale + {i, j} & /@ data, 2];
data = Flatten[p1, 1];
p2 = Partition[Flatten[Nearest[coords, data], 1], 2];
Mean@Array[
 EuclideanDistance[Flatten[p1, 1][[#]], Flatten[p2, 1][[#]]] &, 
 24], {i, x = 95, 130}, {j, y = 17, 50}];
pos = First@Position[mean, Min@mean] + {x - 1, y - 1};
p1 = {{{5, 80}, {20, 100}}, {{15, 90}, {35, 90}}, {{15, 75}, {35, 
 75}}, {{5, 55}, {35, 55}}, {{20, 25}, {35, 35}}, {{25, 30}, {25, 
 75}}, {{45, 85}, {85, 85}}, {{45, 85}, {45, 20}}, {{85, 85}, {85,
  20}}, {{45, 25}, {85, 25}}, {{45, 55}, {85, 55}}, {{60, 
 85}, {65, 100}}};
data = Flatten[p1, 1];
p1 = Partition[#*scale + pos & /@ data, 2];
data = Flatten[p1, 1];
p2 = Partition[Flatten[Nearest[coords, data], 1], 2];
Graphics[{Point[coords], Green, Line[p1], Red, Line@p2}]
p2
```

[image]

> {{{115.317, 38.4167}, {115.48, 38.87}}, {{115.317, 38.4167}, {116.1, 
>      38.45}}, {{115.567, 38}, {116.1, 38.45}}, {{115.36, 37.37}, {116.3,
>       37.45}}, {{115.68, 36.85}, {115.68, 36.85}}, {{115.68, 
>      36.85}, {115.567, 38}}, {{116.1, 38.45}, {117.351, 
>      38.3683}}, {{116.1, 38.45}, {115.97, 36.43}}, {{117.351, 
>      38.3683}, {117.491, 36.7583}}, {{115.97, 36.43}, {117.491, 
>      36.7583}}, {{116.3, 37.45}, {117.217, 37.7333}}, {{116.87, 
>      38.32}, {116.87, 38.32}}}

and you can try different scales

```
scale = .04;
```

[image]

```
scale = .08;
```

[image]

```
scale = .12;
```

[image]

or make a Table for scales and choose the best one (but it will take some time to calculate)

Comment: Thanks. So much neater approach than mine. So many built in functions I didn't realise existed.